# Print flat directory structure from root to child in java

Tags: java, python, file, data-structures, tree

I have a flat file directory structure stored in a csv file which contains

```
id; parentId; name; type; size; classification; checksum;
1;3;file1;file;10;Secret;42;
2; ;folder2;directory; ; ; ;
3;11;folder3;directory; ; ; ;
4;2;file4;file;40;Secret;42;
5;3;file5;file;50;Public;42;
6;3;file6;file;60;Secret;42;
7;3;file7;file;70;Public;42;
8;10;file8;file;80;Secret;42;
9;10;file9;file;90;Top secret;42;
10;11;folder10;directory; ; ; ;
11;2;folder11;directory; ; ; ;
```

[image: Image showing the tree structure]

we need to arrange the structure as tree hierarchy by using id and parent id. I am able to do it manually where
it showed in the figure. But when it comes to coding i am not able to find exact solution using correct data structure.
the output should be in the form of root folder to base folder or files when printing the folder it should print the 
size of the files and folders in that folder. An appropriate java or python solution will be helpful

```
name = folder2, type = Directory, size = 400
name = file4, type = File, size = 40, classification = Secret, checksum = 42
name = folder11, type = Directory, size = 360
name = folder10, type = Directory, size = 170
name = file8, type = File, size = 80, classification = Secret, checksum = 42
name = file9, type = File, size = 90, classification = Top secret, checksum = 42
name = folder3, type = Directory, size = 190
name = file1, type = File, size = 10, classification = Secret, checksum = 42
name = file5, type = File, size = 50, classification = Public, checksum = 42
name = file6, type = File, size = 60, classification = Secret, checksum = 42
name = file7, type = File, size = 70, classification = Public, checksum = 42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **very** basic Java implementation.

```
    HashMap<String, Set<String>> nodes = new HashMap<>();
    File file = new File("E:/test.txt");

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file.toPath())) {
        stream.forEach((line) -> {
            String parts[] = line.split(";");
            nodes.putIfAbsent(parts[0], new HashSet<>());
            nodes.putIfAbsent(parts[1], new HashSet<>());
            nodes.get(parts[1]).add(parts[0]);
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code maps children files to their parents. This is a lazy method of implementing a tree wherein you know about all of the nodes and their children, which is all information presented in the flat file directory structure. It streams the file line by line; at each line it takes the node id and parent id, creates nodes for either of them if they don't exist before adding the node id to the parent id children set.

The node HashMap looks like this at this stage:

`{ =[2], 11=[3, 10], 1=[], 2=[11, 4], 3=[1, 5, 6, 7], 4=[], 5=[], 6=[], 7=[], 8=[], 9=[], 10=[8, 9]}`

If you are happy with treating the `" "` String as the root, you can begin recursively traversing through the list by retrieving the root `nodes.get(" ");`, otherwise you will need to define how you retrieve the root node.

One potential way of adopting this approach while maintaining the information is to treat each File as a Node.

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    HashMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodes = new HashMap<>();
    File file = new File("E:/test.txt");

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file.toPath())) {
        stream.forEach((line) -> {
            String parts[] = line.split(";");
            Node node = new Node(parts);
            Node parent = new Node(parts[1]);

            nodes.putIfAbsent(parent, new HashSet<>());
            nodes.putIfAbsent(node, new HashSet<>());
            nodes.get(parent).add(node);
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    calculateSize(nodes, new Node(" "));
    traverse(nodes, new Node(" "));

}

public static void traverse(HashMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodes, Node root) {
    System.out.println(root);
    for (Node child : nodes.get(root)) {
        traverse(nodes, child);
    }
}

public static int calculateSize(HashMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodes, Node root) {
    int size = root.getSize();
    for (Node child : nodes.get(root)) {
        size += calculateSize(nodes, child);
    }
    root.setSize(size);
    return size;
}

public static class Node {
    private String id = " ";
    private String type= " ";
    private String name = " ";
    private int size = 0;
    private String classification = " ";
    private int checksum = 0;

    public Node (String[] parts) {
        this.id = parts[0];
        this.name = parts[2];
        this.type = parts[3];
        this.classification = parts[5];
        if (this.type.equals("file")) {

            this.size = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
            this.checksum = Integer.valueOf(parts[6]);
        }
    }

    public Node (String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (name.equals(" ")) return "Root";
        String toString = (name.equals(" ")) ? "" : String.format("name = %s", name);
        toString += (type.equals(" ")) ? "" : String.format(", type = %s", type);
        toString += String.format(", size = %d", size);
        toString += (classification.equals(" ")) ? "" : String.format(", classification = %s", classification);
        toString += String.format(", checksum = %d", checksum);
        return toString;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Node) {
            return ((Node) o).id.equals(this.id);
        } else if (o instanceof String) {
            return o.equals(this.id);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id.hashCode();
    }

    public int getSize() { return size; }
    public void setSize(int size) { this.size = size; }
}
```

The recursive search allows you to traverse through the nodes and print them to console. Note I've overriden the equals, hashCode and toString methods. The equals and hashCode allow you to avoid duplicates and ensure node association is retained.

If you're wanting to sum the files up, you can, as I have suggested, use recursion to calculate the sum for a specific directory and all it's children.

Your question is extremely unclear as to what you want. Please be more clear next time.

As a side note: You're diagram is incorrect. 7 is only a sub-directory of 3, not 10.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but i have already done the part of map and values in the python. But im unable to move forward using recursive. Can u please tell the solution for that

Comment: How to sum up the checksums of the files  from root to child ? Like in the solution.

Comment: "Like in the solution" - Your question is extremely vague and unclear.

Answer (score -1):

You could make 2 classes `File` and `Folder` where you can override the `__str__()` method in those classes to what you need.